# Deploying my AIDL that imports my classes

Tags: android, service, aidl

I have to make other developers to be able to connect to my service, but my AIDL imports my classes.
I don't want to give them the source code of the service, just the APK and some kind of a stub file (java, jar?).
How can I give them something - "the glue" - which makes them to use the classes in my AIDL and using the service akp without getting the sources of the service?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

> I have to make other developers to be able to connect to my service, but my AIDL imports my classes

If by "my classes" you mean your own classes that implement `Parcelable`, get rid of them from your API.

IMHO, the only stable remote service APIs are ones that depend solely on things supplied and managed by the operating system. That means you stick to primitives, lists/maps, and `Parcelable` classes supplied by Android (e.g., `Bundle`, `PendingIntent`).

Otherwise, you have to ship the source code to your `Parcelable` classes, then deal with compatibility issues should you ever decide to change those class implementations.

If, however, "my classes" refers to something else, you may wish to edit your question and explain a bit further what you mean. For example, you might post the AIDL file.

Comment: The problem is that the API (through this AIDL) needs the special classes (parcelable). So, if I get rid of them, how will the client code make use of them? How can I export some kind of a stub/glue that makes it possible to see the classes without using the sources? (the classes are just for passing/retrieving data)

Comment: @user289463: "The problem is that the API (through this AIDL) needs the special classes (parcelable)" -- IMHO, that was an API design mistake on your part, if you were planning on third parties connecting to this AIDL interface. For your own projects, custom `Parcelable` classes are fine, but not for APIs for third parties. "How can I export some kind of a stub/glue that makes it possible to see the classes without using the sources?" -- you don't. You redesign your API to avoid the use of custom `Parcelables`. For example, switch them to `Bundles`.

Comment: (well, it wasn't designed/written by me, but I have to deal with it now)

What if I try to put all the classes (simplified) that affect the AIDL into a separate package which I distribute then?
Will the 3rd party program be able to use those similarly built (same functions, but with no code) classes to retrieve information via the AIDL/binding from the service that uses the original version of the classes (same functions, but the real code inside)?